# Connect two slides with one section of top heading in Latex Beamer.

Tags: beamer, themes

In below code made two slides of a presentation. In the first slide, section part is active when I am on the first slide. and the Second slide also I would like to connect with the same section of the first slide. meanwhile, it will remain active until leave second slide.

```
\documentclass[handout,t]{beamer}
\begin{document}
% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{5 Years’ activities}
\begin{frame}{Past 5 Years’ activities}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Ocean modeling – study of El Nino

    \item Study of Carbon monitoring
    \item climate change

\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{}
\begin{frame}{Next 5 Years’ activities}
\begin{itemize}
    \item climate change mitigation
    \item Study of ground water 
    \item Satellite data of cloud –  climatology

\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the `\section{}` supposed to do?

Comment: Nothing, that's why I keep it blank, what i supposed to write there to connect with first slide of section line

Comment: Thanks . By the removed the `\section{} ` line, i overcome the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LaTeX is a markup language. That means that the structure you build up with commands like `\section` structures your document. So even if you give it `{}` as an argument LaTeX will think it's a new section that's independent from the one before.

Hence, you should put all what belongs to one section into one section. That's why your `\section{}` can be omitted and LaTeX knows again which section the slide belongs to and which title to put on it.